# Batch File To Loop Menu

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch file that will launch when I login to my user account. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/78083-batch-files-create-menu-execute-commands.html) to create a batch file with a menu. It works, however, if the user enters a number that is not listed, I want it to go back to the menu. How would I implement that?

**Side note:** I understand I could use something more flexible like Powershell, however, I prefer batch files.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
echo Welcome %USERNAME%

echo 1 - Start KeePass
echo 2 - Backup
echo 3 - Exit

SET /P M=Type 1,2,3 then press Enter:


IF %M%==1 GOTO StarKeePass
IF %M%==2 GOTO Backup
IF %M%==3 GOTO :EOF


:StarKeePass
SET keePass="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\KeePass-2.30\KeePass.exe"
SET kdb="%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\PasswordDatabase\PasswordDatabase.kdbx"

echo I'll start KeePass for You
START "" %keePass% %kdb% 

GOTO MENU

:Backup
SET backup="%USERPROFILE%\backup.bat"
call %backup%

GOTO MENU
```

Comment: Put a `GOTO MENU` after your IF commands

Comment: a little confused, you mean right after the last IF put a GOTO menu

Comment: yes. You also should take a look to `choice /?`

Comment: also the built-in EOF label is to be called with a colon: `goto :eof`

Comment: @iluvlinux, it is no different then the **OTHER TWO TIMES** you are using `GOTO MENU`.

Comment: As @Squashman said, you should use GOTO MENU after `IF %M%==3 GOTO :EOF` I suggest instead of following a tutorial, look at ss64.com, starting [here](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a menu using `set /P`, I recommend the following changes:

- after all the `if` queries, put a `goto :MENU` to catch unintended entries;
- reset the selection variable by something like `set "SELECT="` before the `set /P` command, because `set /P` keep the former value of the variable in case the user presses just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>;
- put quotes `""` around the expressions in the `if` statements to avoid syntax errors in case the variable is empty or it contains some characters that have special meanings (`^` `&` `(` `)` `<` `>` `|`; the `"` character still causes problems though);
- use the quoted syntax `set [/P] "SELECT=anything"` to avoid trouble with special characters;
- in case letters are queried, add the `/I` switch to `if` to force case-insensitive comparison;
- if you wish, you could put a `cls` command after the `:MENU` label to let the screen be built up every time you return to the menu;

Here is an example that demonstrates what I am talking about:

```
@echo off

:MENU
cls
echo --- MAIN MENU ---
echo 1 - do something
echo 2 - do something else
echo Q - quit

set "SELECT="
set /P "SELECT=Type 1, 2, or Q <Enter>: "
if "%SELECT%"=="1" GOTO :SOMEWHERE
if "%SELECT%"=="2" GOTO :SOMEWHERE_ELSE
if /I "%SELECT%"=="Q" GOTO :EOF
goto :MENU

:SOMEWHERE
rem do something here...
echo.
echo Print some text.
pause
goto :MENU

:SOMEWHERE_ELSE
rem do something else here...
echo.
echo Print some other text.
pause
goto :MENU
```

---

To avoid the above mentioned troubles with the `"` character, modify the `set /P` block as follows:

```
set "SELECT=""
set /P "SELECT=Type 1, 2, or Q <Enter>: "
set "SELECT=%SELECT:"=%"
if "%SELECT%"=="1" GOTO :SOMEWHERE
if "%SELECT%"=="2" GOTO :SOMEWHERE_ELSE
if /I "%SELECT%"=="Q" GOTO :EOF
goto :MENU
```